# how to recover the genericWritable to my user-defined Writable in the reduce of hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop

I want to use GenericWritable to implement different value type of the same key in map-reduce stream. For example I create two user-defined class for different value type, here is one of my user-defined value class:

```
public user_def_Value1 extends writableComparable<user_def_Value1> {
       private var1;
       private var2;
       ......
       public void setAsCopy(user_def_Value1 other) {
              var1.set(other.var1);
              var2.set(other.var2);
       }
       ......
}
```

Then I use GenericWritable to carry on my two user-defined value classes as the output value of my mapper. here is my GenericWritable implementation

```
public class GenericValue extends GenericWritable  {

    private static Class<? extends Writable>[] CLASSES = null;

    static {
        CLASSES = (Class<? extends Writable>[]) new Class[] {
            user_def_Value1.class,
            user_def_Value2.class
        };
    }

    //this empty initialize is required by hadoop
    public GraphCleanGenericValue() {
    }

    public GraphCleanGenericValue(Writable instance) {
        set(instance);
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<? extends Writable>[] getTypes() {
        return CLASSES;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return get().toString();
    }
}
```

my question is in the reducer methods, when I use values.next() to get a generic value, how to convert this generic value to my user-defined class instance. Here is my implementation about the reducer(), but I am not sure whether it is a safe down cast.

```
public void reduce(key, Iterator<GenericValue> values,
                OutputCollector<outputKey, outputValue> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
            user_def_Value1 temp = new user_def_Value1();
            temp.setAsCopy((user_def_Value1) values.next().get());
            ......
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `instanceof`.
For example:

```
Writable value = values.next().get();
if (value instanceof SomeClassName) {
    // do something;
} 
else if (value instanceof AnotherClassName) {
    // do something;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is not really about Hadoop.  It's about doing variant types in Java. There are about [8 ways](http://jazzjuice.blogspot.com/2010/10/6-things-i-hate-about-java-or-scala-is.html) and they all suck in varying degrees.